# Storing MemoryStream File to Azure Blob

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-blob-storage, memorystream

I have an image that gets dynamically generated via System.Drawing. I am then outputting the generated image to a `MemoryStream` for storage into my Azure blob.

But I can't seem to get my file to store in the blob of my choice. There are no errors occurring and my image is successfully getting saved to `MemoryStream`. As expected, my blob is empty.

I have ensured my blob container has public read/write access.

### Code

```
// Retrieve storage account from connection string.
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(String.Format("DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName={0};AccountKey={1}", Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue("CMSAzureAccountName").ToString(), Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue("CMSAzureSharedKey").ToString()));

// Create the blob client.
CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

// Retrieve reference to a previously created container.
CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("myimagecontainer");

// Retrieve reference to a blob named "myblob".
CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("test.jpg");
            
//Output image
ImageCodecInfo[] Info = System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders();
EncoderParameters Params = new System.Drawing.Imaging.EncoderParameters(1);
Params.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(Encoder.Quality, 100L);

System.IO.MemoryStream msImage = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
GenerateImage.Render(imageOutput).Save(msImage, Info[1], Params); //GenerateImage.Render() method creates a custom image and returns a Bitmap
            
// Create or overwrite the "myblob" blob with contents from a local file.
using (var fileStream = msImage)
{
    blockBlob.UploadFromStream(fileStream);
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

### Update

I managed to find what the main cause of the error. I needed to change the following:

```
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(String.Format("DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName={0};AccountKey={1}", Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue("CMSAzureAccountName").ToString(), Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue("CMSAzureSharedKey").ToString()));
```

to

```
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue("DiagnosticsConnectionString"));
```

But I will mark "Gaurav Mantri" response as correct. If it wasn't for his insight, my image would not have uploaded to the blob.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Try and set the Position of your memory stream to 0 and see if that helps. Something like the code below:

```
msImage.Position = 0;//Move the pointer to the start of stream.

// Create or overwrite the "myblob" blob with contents from a local file.
using (var fileStream = msImage)
{
    blockBlob.UploadFromStream(fileStream);
}
```

Comment: Ah! I actually got the following error message: "Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature."

Comment: That would usually mean there's an issue with your account name/key stored in the the config file. Can you try doing a simple operation like creating a blob container and see if you get an error there or not. You could simply do container.CreateIfNotExists() after you've created an instance of CloudBlobContainer in your code above.

Comment: Thanks for your help Gaurav. I found the problem was due to the CloudStorageAccount connection string. But I have marked your response as correct since it helped with the upload file issue.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, the code works but the pdf file size was always 0, I had to make the MyMemoryStream.Position = 0; below is the code I have used. Hope it helps someone.

```
using (pdfStream)
{
    pdfStream.Position = 0;
    blob.UploadFromStream(pdfStream);                            
    _model.ConvertedPdfUrl = blob.Uri.AbsoluteUri;
}
```